# Using PAM to unlock pass (gpg-preset-passphrase)

Tags: linux, gnupg, pam, gpg-agent

I'm using [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/) as my password manager with the [browserpass](https://github.com/browserpass/browserpass-extension) plugin and [passmenu](https://git.zx2c4.com/password-store/tree/contrib/dmenu). Currently I have to unlock my GPG keys manually in the console before I can use the plugin on a website (otherwise it fails with an error stating that it can't decrypt the password file) or passmenu (fails without error).

I would like to automatically unlock my GPG keys on login to seamlessly use pass. From my research I gathered the following:

- GPG keys can be unlocked without timeout using [`gpg-preset-passphrase`](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Invoking-gpg_002dpreset_002dpassphrase.html#Invoking-gpg_002dpreset_002dpassphrase)
- PAM (with [`pam_exec`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_exec)) allows me to integrate that into the login process

I've created `/usr/local/bin/gpg-pam-exec`

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# read pam provided password token
read token

su $PAM_USER -c "/usr/local/bin/gpg-preset-passphrase" <<< "$token"
```

and `/usr/local/bin/gpg-preset-passphrase`

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# read pam provided password token
read token

# get the keygrips of my GPG keys
fingerprints=($(gpg -K --fingerprint --with-colons | sed -nr '/fpr/,+1{s/^grp:+(.*):$/\1/p}'))

# preset each fingerprint
for fingerprint in "${fingerprints[@]}"
do
    /usr/libexec/gpg-preset-passphrase -v -c "$fingerprint" <<< "$token"
done
```

and made them executable with `chmod a+x`. Then I appended

```bsh
session     optional    pam_exec.so log=/var/log/pam_exec.log expose_authtok /usr/local/bin/gpg-pam-exec
```

to `/etc/pam.d/slim` and made sure that I have `allow-preset-passphrase` in `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` and `use-agent` in `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`.

Running `/usr/local/bin/gpg-preset-passphrase` manually yields the desired result. However, after rebooting and logging in I have the following in `/var/log/pam_exec.log`:

```bsh
*** Thu May  2 10:49:38 2019
gpg-preset-passphrase: caching passphrase failed: Not implemented
gpg-preset-passphrase: caching passphrase failed: Not implemented
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here. I've convinced myself that the script is running as the correct user (`echo $(id -un)`), which lead me to believe that the [`gpg-agent`](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT.html) ignores the config file.

I've tried adding

```bsh
gpgconf --kill gpg-agent
gpg-agent --options /home/$PAM_USER/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf --daemon
```

to `/usr/local/bin/gpg-preset-passphrase`, but that didn't work either.

Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Comment: fwiw, I don't have `/usr/libexec` on my system (Arch) - my `gpg-preset-passphrase` is at `/usr/lib/gnupg`

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a project that does precisely this: [cruegge/pam-gnupg](https://github.com/cruegge/pam-gnupg)

Also a simple script here: [Apsu/5893348](https://gist.github.com/Apsu/5893348) which seems to be written as a proof-of-concept for [envoy](https://github.com/vodik/envoy) - see [this issue](https://github.com/vodik/envoy/issues/6)